# insert data from Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, linked-server

I have a dynamic sql statement that runs on a remote linked server.
I can run the statement like this

```
exec (@sql) at MylinkedServer
```

The data comes back ok, but that's where the issue starts.
I can't seem to do anything locally with the result set.
I can't insert it into a local table or a temp table.

Eg:

```
insert into #results exec(@sql) at DC105WCSV712
```

Can some one show me how this could be achieved ?

Comment: does your exec statement has a return?

Comment: show us the code of @sql

Answer (score 0):

if your getting a single return variable you can do:

```
declare @localVariable int
exec @localVariable =GetMyValue
select @localVariable
```

And then

insert the @localVariable in your table